# How to connect two points from vector with lines with set y value?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a vector a with values

```
0.4000     0.4604
```

How to connect points with y value for instance 5 and x values of vector? I mean [0.4 0.46] using a vector and lets say y variable.

```
a
y = 5
```

one point is [0.4,5] and the second one [0.4604,5]

Comment: "connect points"? Are you talking about drawing a line between the two points?

Comment: Please read the documentation of [`plot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html)

Comment: You mean something like this?  `x = [0.4 0.4604]';`, `yval = 5;`, `plot(x,yval*ones(size(x)),'k-')`    This has been made easier with [`yline`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/yline.html) since R2018b.

Answer (score 1):

```
X = [0.4, 0.46];
Y = [5, 5];
plot(X, Y);
```

Comment: Thank you and how to do arrow with two heads instead of line?

Comment: For instance like in the picture below https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/160487-how-can-i-draw-a-line-with-arrow-head-between-2-data-points-in-a-plot 
`y = [0.4 0.4];    
Xadj = 1.35;      % adjust location of left arrow starting point (the sum of this with 'x' should not be negative)
annotation('textarrow',x,y,'String',' Growth  ','FontSize',13,'Linewidth',2)
annotation('textarrow',-x+Xadj,y,'String','','FontSize',14,'Linewidth',2)`
I don't understand the numbers in it. What it 0.4 0.4?